# How to find the Process ID (PID) of a running terminal program?

Tags: command-line, process

I am running a program in the terminal that I can't escape with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and that I want to kill. How can I find its PID?

Comment: This is a branch of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) as a reference to prevent details in that question from becoming too technical.

Comment: There is a *pidof* command.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Open another terminal and run `ps ax  | grep foo` where foo is the name of the unresponsive program. This should return a line of output  that looks something like this:

```
$ ps ax | grep firefox
2222 ?        S      0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.9/firefox
2231 ?        Sl   514:36 /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.9/firefox-bin
30290 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

The first field of each line of output is a number which represents the Process ID of the program matched by `grep` (you can safely ignore the last one, which represents `grep` itself.

To halt the offending process, do:
`kill pid` where pid is the Process ID of the program. You might have to use your judgment as to which of the matches needs to be `kill`ed, or you could use `top` instead. Using `kill` by itself sends SIGTERM, which you should try first as it allows the program to properly clean up after itself. If SIGTERM fails, try SIGHUP, which is stonger medicine: `kill -HUP pid`. If all else fails, send SIGKILL. But, you should only do so as a last resort, because SIGKILL causes the kernel to terminate the process immediately with no possibility for cleanup. This can at times result in data corruption or other problems. So again, only send SIGKILL as a last resort. To do so, do `kill -KILL pid` or `kill -9 pid`.

If you are running a graphical interface, of course, you don't have to fool with this crazy command-line stuff to get the job done. Just open "System Monitor", navigate to the Processes tab, choose the process you want to halt (Hm, could it be the one using 90% CPU?) and right-click it. Since the process is already stopped, (that's the problem, right?) choose End Process or Kill Process from the resulting menu.

> *Credit to [koanhead](https://askubuntu.com/users/2315/koanhead)*

Comment: People should never use SIGKILL (kill -9) unless all other methods have failed. Only listing `kill -9` is bad advice. I've edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: How can I find the pid of a custom function. I have a function that contains a loop with a `ping` command and `sleep`. According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275826/72988 , it is not possible in Ubuntu without `multiplexer`.

Comment: To get all open `programs` by id would not be possible because then you have also all `services` and end with `ps -ef`?

Answer (score 82):

I don't think there is any need of such long commands when you can accomplish the same commands with pgrep, pkill, pidof etc...

To get the PID of a running program you can use commands like `pgrep` or `pidof`:

#### pgrep

```
pgrep [options] pattern
```

`pgrep` looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which match the selection criteria to stdout.  All the criteria have to match.  For example,

- To find process named sshd owned by root.

  ```
  $ pgrep -u root sshd
  ```
- List the processes owned by root OR daemon.

  $ pgrep -u root,daemon
- List the processes searching the full command line (`-f`) and list the full command line as well as the process ID (`-a`).

  ```
  $ pgrep -fa needle
  ```

#### pidof

`pidof` finds  the process id's (pids) of the named programs. It prints those id's on the standard output.

pidof program_name

To kill a program by pid use `pkill`. Example:

```
pkill pid    
pkill -f process_name    
pkill -o process_name    
pkill -n process_name    
pkill -l process_name
```

- `-f` flag: Searches the process_name (see man pkill)
- `-o` flag: Select only the oldest of the matching processes.
- `-n` flag: Select only the newest of the matching processes.
- `-l` flag: List the process name as well as the process ID.

Comment: Why is `pidof` returning 2 pids?

Comment: @CrazyVideoGamer if two processes of the same program are running it returns two pids

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way to know the pid of a running program is using:

```
pidof <application name>
```

For example, if you started vim and want to know its pid:

```
pidof vim
```

Remember that you will need to provide the exact program name that has been started.

For example, if you are running vi and execute `pidof vim` you won't get correct results.

Refer to `pidof`'s manual page for more info.

Comment: This isn't installed by default. It might be in the sysvinit-utils package.

Comment: I got MariaDB. `pidof mysqld` returns a PID. However, if I type `pidof Mariadb` nothing is returned. Is it the same PID for both MariaDB and MySQL?

Answer (score 30):

I have found it is nice to use a case insensitive search by adding the "-i" and using "aux" instead of "ax" to get a more descriptive output:

```
ps aux | grep -i firefox
```

If you would like to kill all the processes you may use:

```
ps aux | grep -i firefox | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

That is a forceful kill. Drop the "-9" if you want a soft kill.

Comment: This also kills the `ps aux | grep -i firefox...` process, because that contains the text `firefox` in its command!

Comment: @Eric you could use ```grep -i firefo[x]``` to match only firefox

Comment: @john-foley never advise to use ```-9``` with ```kill```, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process#8927) for explanations

Comment: `ps aux | grep -i firefox | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9` to omit the killing of the grep statement itself

Answer (score 8):

If you want only the pid (useful for autokill scripts, etc...)

```
pgrep -f desired_program_name
```

Answer (score 2):

For those running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, *you **must** use `ps ax` and not just `ps`* at the command line, otherwise you will just get the processes spawning from the particular terminal instance that you're in. (usually just 'bash' [the shell you're in] and 'ps' [what you just ran])

Comment: I like `ps -e` (shows all) and `ps -ejH` (shows a process tree).

Comment: @Andrew nice, that's actually pretty sweet -- thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

To get PIDs for all running services, you can use this command:

```
pstree -p -a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also open another terminal (or switch to another tty) and run `top`, which is basically a text version of the System Monitor. The first column lists the PID of each running process, which you can kill by pressing <kbd>K</kbd>, entering the PID and then entering a numeric signal to send.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
ps ax | grep firefox | cut -f2 -d" " - | xargs kill -9
```

first two pipes get process info, next we try to get PID column by using the old-school cut and then we give the resulting PID to kill.

Comment: `kill -9` is the biggest gun you have to kill a process. You should try a more gentle signal at first before resorting to SIGKILL to give the process a chance to clean up its resources.

Comment: That's true @ByteCommander. I wanted to make it a one liner that will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```
top
```

or

```
screen -list|ls
```

list all pid with corresponding process

```
kill -[pid]
```

Answer (score 0):

sed (stream editor) for process id(s) or `pgrep`:

```
echo $(p="bash"; ps -e | sed -E "s/^ +([[:digit:]]+).+${p}$/# \1/;s/^[^#].+$//;/^$/d;" -)
```