# Netbeans 7.4 refuses to close?

Tags: 13.10, netbeans

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and have netbeans 7.4 whenever I close netbeans it restart and keep doing that until I restart my computer and same story.

#### Edit

can I do something with netbeans which close it and I am not asking for finding process id and kill it. 

Downloaded the netbeans from its [website](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=php) `.sh` extension.

NetBeans IDE 7.4
if I try to run it with sudo from terminal `sudo netbeans` it says `sudo: netbeans: command not found`
If netbeans is installed with `sudo apt-get install netbeans` its fine and have no problem but they have older version netbeans 7.0.1

what should I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

- First run `ps aux | grep netbeans` command.It will display netbeans program along with it's pid.
- Note the pid and kill the program by running,

  ```
  sudo kill <pid>
  ```

Comment: thats not a real solution right ?

Comment: why it's not a right solution?

Comment: well, every time you have to find the id and then kill it imagine it doing every time you have to close a software you use frequently

Comment: no your answer help somehow but thats not complete solution so i would say no you dont delete it

Comment: no I do not know the answer, thats why I asked it

Comment: `ps aux | grep netbeans` does the job instead `ps -ef` [reference:](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180336/how-to-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-running-terminal-program)

Comment: did you want my above answer to edit with the above command you mentioned?

Comment: sure ! That would help people who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will end up with this

```
killall java
```

this Will kill all java related apps as well including netbeans in your user processes

to kill All java apps with all users use **sudo**

```
sudo killall java
```

Answer (score 0):

I think net-beans doesn't have privileges to update its state .

try `sudo` to start netbeans

Comment: `sudo netbeans` doesnt work ! how to run it as `sudo` then ?

Comment: I downloaded the netbeans from its [website](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=php) the .sh extension and installed so now I cant seem to run it from terminal with command `sudo netbeans` and refuses to close whenever I close it

Comment: try sudo pkill -9 netbeans

Comment: No, it doesn't do anything !

Comment: is there any logs about netbeans in /var/log/syslog

Comment: No, there isn't anything about netbeans in syslog

Answer (score 0):

To install netbeans follow this command:

```
sudo sh netbeans-*.sh
```