# What has problem, when cursor is movable and everything else is not working?

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

Some times my Ubuntu 14.04 becomes frozen (only the window of the program running on top of others is seen but not responsive), while my mouse cursor is still  movable, but clicking it doesn't make any change. In such case, which par is going wrong:

- X window system
- window manager (e.g. compiz, metacity)
- desktop environment (e.g. unity, gnome)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is `compiz` fault. You can wait like 1 minute and it'll be back.

It not, you can restart it without loose any data.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open `tty1` and run this command to restart it:

```
compiz --replace
```

If even this way `compiz` don't want to restart, [find the process, kill it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180336/how-to-find-the-process-id-pid-of-a-running-terminal-program) and then run above command again.

Comment: Thanks. is metacity less buggy than compiz? Is it worth to replace compiz with metacity?

Comment: You can only if you don't want to run Unity, as Unity, for now, it's implemented as a compiz plugin (version 8 will be compiz free).